# Spice support disabled in qemu

Tags: kvm, qemu, spice

I'm pretty knew to virtualization and linux in general and I'm having issues getting spice to work with qemu.

I'm trying to install a windows 10 machine using virt-manager on Arch, and the installation refuses to work. Whenever I try to install the machine, it spits out the following error:

Unable to complete install: 'internal error: process exited while connecting to monitor: Failed to open module: libssl.so.3: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
qemu-system-x86_64: -spice port=5900,addr=127.0.0.1,disable-ticketing=on,image-compression=off,seamless-migration=on: spice support is disabled'

I *think* I have spice installed correctly, but I'm not really sure as the spice docs don't really make a lot of sense to me, and spice as a whole is also very confusing to me.

I'm running Xero Linux on a Acer 5 (A515-45).

Kindly let me know if you require anymore information and/or details.

Cheers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Failed to open module: libssl.so.3

This suggests you're missing the OpenSSL libraries.

If you've installed qemu with your package manager, it might've brought in spice (libspice/spice-server/etc..., depending on your distro) as a dependency and everything else it needs - including OpenSSL (e.g. libssl).

Without more info or context, it's hard to guess, but try and install the OpenSSL libraries, better yet, figure out the dependencies for qemu on your distro and try to accommodate that.

I see Xero is based on Arch, so it would look something like this on an actual Arch system:

```
$ pacman -Qo /usr/lib/libssl.so.3
/usr/lib/libssl.so.3 is owned by openssl 3.0.7-2
$ pacman -Q openssl
openssl 3.0.7-2
```

You can check if you have missing files from installed packages, e.g.:

```
$ pacman -Qk qemu-system-x86
qemu-system-x86: 13 total files, 0 missing files
```

You can use `pacman -T` to check dependencies of installed packages to see if something is amiss with your qemu installation.

Comment: Upon looking into what OpenSSL packages I had installed and installing the missing package, it works just fine now. Thanks!